# Function as a type?

Tags: c++, windows

I am learning Windows programming in C++. I created my first Windows, but there's one thing I don't really understand: WNDPROC in WNDCLASS. The structure was documented like this:

```
typedef struct tagWNDCLASS {
  UINT      style;
  WNDPROC   lpfnWndProc;
  int       cbClsExtra;
  int       cbWndExtra;
  HINSTANCE hInstance;
  HICON     hIcon;
  HCURSOR   hCursor;
  HBRUSH    hbrBackground;
  LPCTSTR   lpszMenuName;
  LPCTSTR   lpszClassName;
} WNDCLASS, *PWNDCLASS;
```

Now in order to assign to lpfnWndProc, I must have a callback function WindowProc like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

And then I have to assign lfpnWndProc like this:

```
WNDCLASS wc = { };

wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
```

As I understand, WindowProc is a function. If I assign like this, it means I am assigning to a function pointer in WNDCLASS. But in the WNDCLASS definition, nothing indicates it is a function pointer. Further more, it looks like a data type to me rather than a function pointer.

Normally I would do get a function pointer like this to pass in as a parameter or used as a variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_int_func(int x)
{
    printf("%d\n",x);
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*foo) (int);
    foo = &my_int_func;

    foo(2);
    (*foo)(2);
}
```

But the way I have to assign WindowProc just does not make sense to me. Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WNDPROC` is a function pointer type.  The definition is:

```
typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK* WNDPROC)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

Functions, sort of like arrays, automatically decay into pointers in certain contexts.  The `&` in your example program is optional.

Comment: Oh I see. But how can you used it like a data type in their struct definition? Also, why does it have to be returned as a CALLBACK before return the LRESULT?

Comment: @Amumu, after that `typedef`, you can use `WNDPROC` like any other type in the system.

Comment: So if I treat it as a type, how about the return value of the function? Since it becomes a type, is it possible to retrieve the value?

Comment: You have to call the function to get a return value - `result = wc.lpfnWndProc(a, b, c, d)` should do exactly what you need it to.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says,

> **lpfnWndProc**
>
> Type: **WNDPROC**
>
> **A pointer to the window procedure.** You must use the CallWindowProc function to call the window procedure.

**WinUser.h** defines it as,

```
typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK* WNDPROC)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

Comment: I'd guess someone was calling you out for a posting a cut&paste answer